# Stock calculation on previous period

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, ssas, mdx

I've a cube of stock analysis.

In the cube there is a Measure called `[Qta Finale]` that is the last stock level of an item.

Then I've a dimension called `[Data]` where there is the calendar.

In the dimension `[Data]` there is a hierarchy called `[Anno Mese]` made as `[Anno]`.

```
[Mese]
[Anno] is the year
[Mese] is the month
```

So I make a calculation

```
Tail(
 NONEMPTY(
 {EXISTING   [Data].[Anno Mese].[Mese].MEMBERS} * [Measures].[Qta Finale]
) ,1).ITEM(0)
```

That works fine. I get the last non empty level of stock in the year and in all months. So all the filters in excel on the calendar works fine.

Now I need to create a new calculation with the level of stock of previous year.

I've try but with no success, any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

If your month-year hierarchy is standard you can use lag to go back 12 months.

```
Tail(
 NONEMPTY(
 {EXISTING   [Data].[Anno Mese].[Mese].MEMBERS} * [Measures].[Qta Finale]
) ,1).ITEM(0).lag(12)
```

Comment: it tell me that I can't use an expression of tuple with a member

Answer (score 0):

Maybe an extra Item required?

```
Tail(
 NONEMPTY(
 {EXISTING   [Data].[Anno Mese].[Mese].MEMBERS} * [Measures].[Qta Finale]
) ,1).ITEM(0).ITEM(0).lag(12)
```

Does this version work?

```
Tail
 (
   EXISTING NONEMPTY([Data].[Anno Mese].[Mese].MEMBERS * [Measures].[Qta Finale])
 ).ITEM(0).ITEM(0).lag(12)
```

---

**Edit1**

Why are you doing a cross join inside the NonEmpty? Maybe just use the measure as a second argument:

```
Tail(
 NONEMPTY(
 {EXISTING   [Data].[Anno Mese].[Mese].MEMBERS}, [Measures].[Qta Finale]
) ,1).ITEM(0).ITEM(0).lag(12)
```

---

**Edit2**

If you're still getting a result that is empty, without any error, then maybe the last existing nonempty member that is 12 back in the set is actually empty.
You can hopefully check by doing these:

```
 SELECT
   {} ON 0,
   [Data].[Anno Mese].[Mese].MEMBERS * [Measures].[Qta Finale] ON 1
 FROM CubeName;

 SELECT
   {} ON 0,
   NONEMPTY([Data].[Anno Mese].[Mese].MEMBERS * [Measures].[Qta Finale]) ON 1
 FROM CubeName;

 SELECT
   {} ON 0,
   {NONEMPTY([Data].[Anno Mese].[Mese].MEMBERS * [Measures].[Qta Finale]).ITEM(0).ITEM(0).lag(12)} ON 1
 FROM CubeName;
```

Then try changing the `*` to a `,`

Comment: ok - you need to inspect the member that is 12 back in the set - I will add a script to help investigate